# How to output an string of ArrayList into a new file?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

Hi guys I have this sample text file in which the names of the peopel are stuck together without any spacing in between them. Is it possible for me to put this into a bufferedreader and create a ArrayList to store the values in a string and then to separate the strings by name.

Text file details:

```
charles_luiharry_pinkertonarlene_purcellwayne_casanova
```

My code:

```
try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    String str;

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(str);
    }
    String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("new_users.txt");
    for (String ss : list) {
        writer.write(ss);
    }
    writer.close();

} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Expected output :

```
charles_lui

harry_pinkerton

arlene_purcell

wayne_casanova
```

Real output:

A duplicate of the sample file.

Comment: Why would it be any different? you only have one line in your input file.

Comment: It's not possible to split up the names without some kind of indication as to where one surname stops and another first name starts.

Comment: Based on your comment on the accepted answer, is this simply a case of handling OS-specific newline separators? E.g. the names are just delimited by `\n`, but Windows (e.g. Notepad) makes it look like they are all in a line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a line separator to your writer:

```
writer.write(ss);
writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
```

If problems with your os, use `System.getProperty( "line.separator" )`

Comment: you mean "writer.write(ss+"\n");" ?

Comment: Thank you Jordi! Just what I needed.

Comment: @Ulaga you're suposing file separator is `\n` what is not correct in all OS, and as far as OP does not provide us this info, better use proposed approach that will work without problems in any platform. ;) also... concatenate `Strings` is sometimes necessary, but in this case looks really ugly.

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader.readLine()` reads and returns a line from the input which ends with `\n` or `\r\n`. It cannot detect the boundaries between the names in your input file. Better prepare the input that the names are on different lines.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult for a human to successfully separate the last-name with first-name of the next name, how can you expect a computer to do so?

Proposed solution -

1. Modify the sample file and add a separator(say ';') between two names.
2. Make a lengthy string by concatenating all the lines in the file. When concatenating remove '\n' or '\r\n' from the end of lines. (Optional - Use a StringBuffer for performance).
3. Split that string into an 'array of valid names'.
   This can be done by calling the split(';') method on the lengthy string, with the separator as the argument.
4. Then, print from the array.